# Folder location for Project->Add Class in Visual Studio 2008 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I like the VS option of Add Class that creates .cpp and .h file for me with a class template in it. But currently i am storing my source files in other folder than project file. Is there a way to to tell VS that i want to create those .cpp and .h files in a specific folder?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, it adds them to whichever project or folder is selected in the Solution Explorer.  In the Solution Explorer, select the place you want the class, right click it and select Add Class.